# what is the the differences between diatonic and chromatic music scales?

Tags: chromatic, diatonic

I'm having trouble understand what the difference between diatonic and chromatic music scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> A **diatonic scale** is any heptatonic scale that includes five whole steps (whole tones) and two half steps (semitones) in each octave, in which the two half steps are separated from each other by either two or three whole steps, depending on their position in the scale. This pattern ensures that, in a diatonic scale spanning more than one octave, all the half steps are maximally separated from each other (i.e. separated by at least two whole steps).

> The **chromatic scale** or twelve-tone scale is a musical scale with twelve pitches, each a semitone, also known as a half-step, above or below its adjacent pitches. As a result, in 12-tone equal temperament (the most common temperament in Western music), the chromatic scale covers all 12 of the available pitches. Thus, there is only one chromatic scale.